# antcall causes FileNotFoundException when using executeTarget from within java

Tags: java, ant, target

i have the same issue [as described here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2102983?start=0). In short: is use ProjectHelper and executeTarget from within a java file to execute an ant target from some ant xml file. However when in this ant file `<antcall>` is used, then i will get a FileNotFoundException that build.xml is missing although calling this ant target "normally" works perfectly fine. There is now reference to build.xml at all so i assume it looks for the standard build.xml and i don't know why. Has this issue been solved somewhere? Couldn't find any help with google.

Comment: Can you show us the ant call target ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem as described. After looking through all the unanswered posts, I found that you have to set the "ant.file" property if not using "build.xml" as the build file...

```
File buildFile = new File(antBuildFilePath);
ProjectHelper.configureProject(projAnt, buildFile);
projAnt.setUserProperty( "ant.file" , buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
//...
```